# Angularjs callback between two controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following controller which upon button click $scope.choose is called. 
$scope.choose calls another page '/detail', using then function I am waiting for callback once item is chosen.

```
App.controller('itemController', function ($scope, itemRepository, $location, chooseService) {        
  $scope.choose = function () {
  $location.path('/detail').then(
    $scope.test =ChooseService.getItem());
  };
});
```

In the '/detail' page when the item is selected submit button is clicked which adds the row value to the service

```
$scope.submit = function(item) {
  ChooseService.addChoose(item);
};
```

This is the service

```
App.service("ChooseService", function () {
  var choose = [];
  this.addChoose = function (newObj) {
    binChoose.push(newObj);
  };

  this.getChoose = function () {
    return choose;
  };
});
```

Html part of the first page is(plunker for html of first page http://plnkr.co/edit/wr8ux520FeUFjbEiO0FY?p=preview

```
  <form name="{{form.name}}"
          ng-repeat="form in forms">

      <h2>{{form.name}}</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="cont in form.contacts">
              <button  ng-click="choose()">Choose</button>
              <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="cont.ac"/>
              <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="cont.a_number"/>
              <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="cont.p_id"/>

      </div>
      <button ng-click="submit(form)">Submit</button>
      <button ng-click="addFields(form)">Add</button>
      <hr>
    </form>
```

Problem I am facing is that in original `itemController` it is not getting call back from the `$scope.submit` which is in the controller for '/detail'

Please let me know how can I fix this code so that once the $scope.submit is called values are loaded in the service it returns back to the `$location.path` above.

Comment: Could you show me some HTML?

Comment: I added the html plus here is the plunker of the page where Choose is pressed and it goes to another page where it lists rows of data and returns and populates the row http://plnkr.co/edit/wr8ux520FeUFjbEiO0FY?p=preview   Thanks